# Cant get char pointer to print correctly

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I am relatively new to pointers, slowly learning how to use them. I have run into a problem here and I have tried all my options. I have a pointer
char* pMonthName; that points to monthName which is a char array.  I tried to print out pMonth with cout << pMonthName; and get garbage and beeping sound.  Also, I have tried printing pMonthName by dereferencing pMonthName            with cout << *pMonthName.  This prints out garbage but closer to the format that I need but the individual characters printed out is garbage.  Can anyone figure out how I can display pMonthName?  Here is the code.

```
char monthName[12][15];

// initialize
strcpy_s(monthName[0], "january");
strcpy_s(monthName[1], "febuary");
strcpy_s(monthName[2], "march");
strcpy_s(monthName[3], "april");
strcpy_s(monthName[4], "may");
strcpy_s(monthName[5], "june");
strcpy_s(monthName[6], "july");
strcpy_s(monthName[7], "august");
strcpy_s(monthName[8], "septempber");
strcpy_s(monthName[9], "october");
strcpy_s(monthName[10], "november");
strcpy_s(monthName[11], "december");

// create a char pointer
char* pMonthName;

// make pointer point to the array
pMonthName = &monthName[12][15];

// print array using the pointer
for (row = 0; row < 12; row++)
{
    length = strlen(monthName[row]); 
    for (col = 0; col < length; col++)
    {
        cout << *pMonthName;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm inb4 `"febuary"` and `"septempber"`. The code you've provided doesn't even compile let alone reproduce the problems you're facing... Shall we close this question, or would you be so kind as to produce an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: inb4 there's no monthName[12]

Comment: `pMonthName = &monthName[12][15];`  What are you doing here?  The compiler already knows that the array is 12 x 15.  All you're doing here is assigning an out-of-bounds address to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, this is all wrong, because it doesn't compile:

> ```
> strcpy_s(monthName[0], "january");
> strcpy_s(monthName[1], "febuary");
> strcpy_s(monthName[2], "march");
> strcpy_s(monthName[3], "april");
> strcpy_s(monthName[4], "may");
> strcpy_s(monthName[5], "june");
> strcpy_s(monthName[6], "july");
> strcpy_s(monthName[7], "august");
> strcpy_s(monthName[8], "septempber");
> strcpy_s(monthName[9], "october");
> strcpy_s(monthName[10], "november");
> strcpy_s(monthName[11], "december");
> ```

I think you're missing an argument (the middle one), which should probably be `15`.

Even if this code were to compile, this is wrong:

> ```
> pMonthName = &monthName[12][15];
> ```

To describe what's wrong with this, consider that an egg carton can store 12 eggs (between `egg_carton[0]` and `egg_carton[11]`), and you're pointing to the thirteenth egg (`egg_carton[12]`).

Worse yet than that, some eggs can be double-yolked, meaning you have `egg_carton[0][0]` and `egg_carton[0][1]` to address the two yolks... but you are pointing at the *third* yolk of the *thirteenth* egg.

... and then you are trying to print that non-existent yolk of that non-existent egg.

`pMonthName` isn't suitable for storing something that requires two levels of indirection, so lets start by fixing that. You'd surely want a *pointer to an array of 12 `char`s* (which you can dereference twice, as though it's *an array of an array*), not just a *pointer to a `char`* (which you can only dereference once, as though it's just *an array*), right? That kind of declaration is written like so:

```
char (*pMonthName)[12];
```

The expression that is `monthName` will be converted from an expression of array (of array) type to an expression of pointer (to array) type. Take a moment to decipher that, perhaps reading it a second (and third) time, before moving on.

There are some exceptions to this rule (for example, operands of the `&address-of` and the `sizeof` operator won't undergo this conversion). You need to understand that these conversions will happen in your code:

- An expression that is `char[15]` implicitly becomes a `char *`.
- An expression that is `char[12][15]` implicitly becomes a `char (*)[15]`.

So if we were to write `pMonthName = monthName;` (or even `monthName[x]`), then `monthName` (which is a `char[12][15]`) will be converted to a `char (*)[15]`. You would then be able to write `pMonthName[index_of_month]` which would be equal to `monthName[index_of_month]`.

**Here's another example**: Given a declaration like `char *pMonthName;`, you could assign the address *one month* (not the array of months) like so: `pMonthName = monthName[index_of_month];`, and `monthName[index_of_month]` (which is a `char[15]`) will be implicitly converted to a `char *` in this expression.

Comment: That strcpy_s usage should be fine since there is a 2 parameter overload which uses a template to deduce the buffer size.